# Existem alternativas para reflexão/introspeção em C++?

Tags: c++, reflexão

Estou com o seguinte problema.

Dado um tipo qualquer `T`:

```
template <typename T>
```

1. Preciso poder converter um objeto do tipo `T` em um mapa `std::unordered_map<std::string, boost::any>` contendo uma entrada para cada atributo. Inicialmente penso em objetos "planos", apenas com atributos primitivos e strings.

   ```
   std::unordered_map<boost::any, boost::any>& asUnordered_map(const T& obj)
   ```
2. Preciso também fazer o contrário, isso é, dado um `std::map<std::string, boost::any>` e um objeto `T` eu quero atualizar os atributos do objeto:

   ```
   T& asObject(const std::unordered_map<boost::any, boost::any>& map)
   ```

Em Java uma implementação natural usaria [`Introspector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html) e técnicas de [reflexão](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

Parece porém que o C++ ainda não suporta reflexão por padrão (o comitê e certos grupos de estudo estão avançando nessa frente [para uma próxima versão](https://root.cern.ch/blog/status-reflection-c)) e emular essa funcionalidade externamente dá um certo trabalho (veja [CPP-Reflection](https://github.com/AustinBrunkhorst/CPP-Reflection)). Dessa forma gostaria de saber se existe alguma alternativa mais idiomática para resolver esse tipo de problema.

Como posso descobrir quais são os atributos de um objeto e como posso recuperar / modificar valores de um tipo de desconhecido em C++?

Comment: Tem que criar alguma solução própria e complexa. Algumas podem ser só baseadas em biblioteca, mas para ficar Firme" mesmo precisa de ferramentas externas como é o caso da Qt: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/moc.html

Comment: Javeiro em C++ é um perigo... Existe alguma alternativa idiomática? Os problemas são aqueles de sempre, serialização e  "desserialização" (não sei se isso é uma palavra) de formatos textuais genéricos.

Comment: Eu não tenho domínio de C++ e desconheço alguma solução simples e "bonita". Pra falar a verdade o MOC é uma das coisas que me faz não gostar tanto da Qt. A alternativa que já achou parece ser uma boa opção. Não quero responder porque seria mais minha opinião que algo que eu sei mesmo.

Comment: Se "os problemas são aqueles de sempre, serialização e desserialização", por que você não usa o [*Serialization* do próprio Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html)? Vc vai ter que fazer o *mashelling* de cada classe, é verdade, mas aí a Orientação a Objetos te ajuda (reutilizando a serialização dos atributos da(s) classe(s) base).

Comment: Ou, tem também o [Ceral](http://uscilab.github.io/cereal/). :)

Comment: Oi @Luiz, pelo que vi ambas as soluções ainda requerem que você implemente algum método dizendo exatamente quais os campos que devem ser serializados em cada tipo de classe (o que eu estou tentando evitar). Além disso o formato de serialização é um XML bem chato e eu já tenho uma solução pronta para persistir / ler algo com um `unordered_map`. Não é o fim do mundo ter que reescrever essa parte se precisar, mas eu gostaria de não ter que implementar um método de serialização para cada objeto se for possível.

Comment: Infelizmente não existe nada atualmente que faça isso. Existem soluções de biblioteca, mas todas elas precisam que você anote os tipos que que você quer introspectar. Um exemplo de biblioteca que permite isso é: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html#tutorial-introspection-adapting

Comment: O [c++/CLI permite reflexao](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0114hz2.aspx)

Comment: Se ainda estiver pensando em criar sua própria solução, vale a pena assistir [C++14 Reflections Without Macros, Markup nor External Tooling..](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abdeAew3gmQ)

Comment: Existe lembre que o Java é escrito em C++ segue o link tutorial de como fazer : http://jackieokay.com/2017/04/13/reflection1.html

Comment: "Todo programa em C suficientemente complexo acaba tendo uma implementação bugada, improvisada, mal especificada e lenta de metade do Lisp" (Décima regra de Greenspun)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar Boost Hana?

https://github.com/boostorg/hana

Você não terá o reflection, mas vai trabalhar com Meta Programação de Verdade.

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
namespace hana = boost::hana;
using namespace hana::literals;

struct Fish { std::string name; };
struct Cat  { std::string name; };
struct Dog  { std::string name; };

int main() {
  // Sequences capable of holding heterogeneous objects, and algorithms
  // to manipulate them.
  auto animals = hana::make_tuple(Fish{"Nemo"}, Cat{"Garfield"}, Dog{"Snoopy"});
  auto names = hana::transform(animals, [](auto a) {
    return a.name;
  });
  assert(hana::reverse(names) == hana::make_tuple("Snoopy", "Garfield", "Nemo"));

  // No compile-time information is lost: even if `animals` can't be a
  // constant expression because it contains strings, its length is constexpr.
  static_assert(hana::length(animals) == 3u, "");

  // Computations on types can be performed with the same syntax as that of
  // normal C++. Believe it or not, everything is done at compile-time.
  auto animal_types = hana::make_tuple(hana::type_c<Fish*>, hana::type_c<Cat&>, hana::type_c<Dog*>);
  auto animal_ptrs = hana::filter(animal_types, [](auto a) {
    return hana::traits::is_pointer(a);
  });
  static_assert(animal_ptrs == hana::make_tuple(hana::type_c<Fish*>, hana::type_c<Dog*>), "");

  // And many other goodies to make your life easier, including:
  // 1. Access to elements in a tuple with a sane syntax.
  static_assert(animal_ptrs[0_c] == hana::type_c<Fish*>, "");
  static_assert(animal_ptrs[1_c] == hana::type_c<Dog*>, "");

  // 2. Unroll loops at compile-time without hassle.
  std::string s;
  hana::int_c<10>.times([&]{ s += "x"; });
  // equivalent to s += "x"; s += "x"; ... s += "x";

  // 3. Easily check whether an expression is valid.
  //    This is usually achieved with complex SFINAE-based tricks.
  auto has_name = hana::is_valid([](auto&& x) -> decltype((void)x.name) { });
  static_assert(has_name(animals[0_c]), "");
  static_assert(!has_name(1), "");
}
```